Torah code raw file
I am about to test some personal theories on the Torah codes. For this I first need a file of some sort which has the entire 5 books, without vowels, commas, dashes etc etc.
Can someone guide me to such a place online?
Else I will need to copy/paste the entire Torah from Sefaria or wherever. Later, I will need to strip away the commas, dashes , vowels etc. which is time consuming.

I'm sure this isn't the best way to do it but I do want to correct your assumption about Sefaria. If you go to "About This Text" on a book of Tanach, scroll down to the download bit, and under "Select Version" choose the "Tanach with text only", you can get it all without vowels and without copy/pasting anything.

Which version do you want?

mechon-mamre.org

Related (on Torah codes): "Tools to validate Torah codes" "Do the Torah codes offer scientific proof that the Torah is supernatural?"

Related (on digitized Torah): "Recommendation for a digital Torah codex for software developers"

@DoubleAA I guess the version given @ Har Sinai. I am not sure I understand the ques.

@mars which version of the ones out there today is that?
